# Есть ли замена тегу bgsound

Tags: css3, html5

Есть ли замена тегу `bgsound`, который будет срабатывать во всех браузерах?

Comment: [было](http://google.com/search?q=site%3Ahashcode.ru+bgsound)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<audio autoplay id="bgsound">
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4"
         type="audio/mp4">
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
         type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis">
<p>Ваш браузер не поддерживает HTML5 Audio элемент.</p>
</audio>
```

Поддержка -  Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari (собственно все те, кто слышал про html5).